Ребят, только начинаю осваивать JS, помогите. Почему не срабатывает код? (Ошибка: message": "TypeError: spanText.indexOf is not a function")


let spanText = document.getElementById('spanText');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (spanText.indexOf('@')) {
    spanText.style.color = 'red';
  }
})
button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
<span id='spanText'>Если в тексте есть @ то меняем цвет на красный.</span>
<button id='btn'>OK</button>




Пробовал (includes) , что более правильнее, но никак не могу изменить цвет всего текста при выполнении поиска нужного элемента в строке

spanText - это HTMLElement - у него нет метода indexOf.
Если нужно получить текст из элемента - можно воспользоваться свойством textContent


let spanText = document.getElementById('spanText');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (spanText.textContent.indexOf('@')) {
    spanText.style.color = 'red';
  }
})
button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
<span id='spanText'>Если в тексте есть @ то меняем цвет на красный.</span>
<button id='btn'>OK</button>




Спасибо огромное. Нужно больше читать.

@ChillyWilly, если этот ответ решил вашу проблему, отметьте его как принятый (галка напротив ответа).
